# Google Script HTML form from Library throws error Uncaught

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, libraries

I have a library with HTML-form like this:

`code.gs`:

```
function openDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("h"), "Test" );
}

function hello() {
  console.log('booo');
}
```

`h.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <button id="b">Click me</button> 
    <script> 
    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    b.onclick = function() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(str){window.alert("executed");})
      // .withFailureHandler(function(error){window.alert("failed");})
      .hello();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I shared this script for view and deployd it as a library. Next I created a bound script in Google Sheet with this code:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('test').addItem('run', 'myFunction').addToUi();
}

var hello = function() {};
function myFunction() {
  TT.openDialog();
}
```

I've added the library with identifier: TT.

Next I refreshed my Google Sheet file with bound code to see the menu "test", ran test > run. The HTML-window appeared. When I clicked the button, nothing happened. When I opened console, I saw the error:

[image]

This error does not appear if I do not use library.

Comment: Have you ran the library by itself and the script on the script editor to give permissions to both scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same situation with you. In my case, the reason of the issue was due to the authorization at the library side.

- When the authorization process for using the scopes in the library is NOT done at the library side, I confirmed that the error of `Uncaught` occurred.
- When the authorization process for using the scopes in the library is done at the library side, I confirmed that the error of `Uncaught` didn't occur.

Namely, in my environment, I confirmed that when the library is used for your situation, it was required to authorize the scopes for both the client side and the library side.

So, as a workaround, I used the following flow.

#### Workaround:

1. Create a Google Apps Script library.

   - Please copy and paste your script of `code.gs` and `h.html` to the standalone script or the container-bound script.
2. Deploy the Google Apps Script as the library.
3. In your script, for example, please directly run `hello()` at the library side, and authorize the scopes.
4. Install the library to the client side and load the library from the client side.
5. Please run `myFunction()` at the client side.

By this flow, when you run `run` at the custom menu and click the button, the dialog of `executed` is opened.

#### Note:

- In this case, when I wanted to make users use the client script, it was required to authorize the scopes for both the client side and the library side. I thought that this may be a little inconvenient.
- So, how about reporting this for the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) Unfortunately, I couldn't find the issue tracker with the same situation.

## Added:

As the method for authorizing the scopes at the library side from the client side, I would like to propose to use Web Apps. I thought that when the Web Apps is used, the authorization of the library side can be done at the client side. By this, I thought that the inconvenience may be resolved a little.

Please do the following flow.

### 1. Library side.

Please copy and paste the following scripts.

#### Google Apps Script: `code.gs`

```
function openDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("h"), "Test" );
}

function hello() {
  console.log('booo');
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("ok");
}
```

#### HTML: `h.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <button id="b">Click me</button> 
    <script> 
    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    b.onclick = function() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(str){window.alert("executed");})
      // .withFailureHandler(function(error){window.alert("failed");})
      .hello();
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### 2. Deploy Web Apps at library side.

Please deploy Web Apps at the library side. About the method for this, you can see the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) The detail setting is as follows.

- `Execute as: User accessing the web app`
- `Who has access: Anyone with Google account`

### 3. Deploy as library.

Please deploy as the library. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

### 4. Client side.

Please install the library to the client side. And, please copy and paste the following scripts. In this case, please replace `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` with your Web Apps URL.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('test').addItem('auth', 'auth').addItem('run', 'myFunction').addToUi();
}

var hello = function() {};
function myFunction() {
  TT.openDialog();
}

function auth() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<input type="button" value="Authorize" onclick="window.open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec', '_blank');google.script.host.close()">`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showDialog(html);
}
```

### 5. Testing.

At first, please run `auth` at the custom menu. By this, you can authorize the scopes of both the client side and the library side. When the new tab is not opened when `auth` is run, please run `auth()` at the script editor again.

As the next step, please run `run`. By this, your dialog is opened. And, when both authorizations (client and library side) with `auth` has already been finished, when you click the button, the dialog of `executed` is opened.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Dear @Tanaike, Thank you for the help. You were the one whom I relied on ;) Bug report is ready: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183305449

Comment: @Max Makhrov Hello. Thank you for replying. And, I starred to the issue tracker.

Comment: @Max Makhrov I noticed the method for authorizing the scopes of both the client side and the library side at the client side. So I added it. Could you please confirm it? By this, I thought that the inconvenience may be resolved a little. But, in the current stage, it seems that it is required to authorize both authorizations (client and library side) for your situation.

Comment: thanks for the solution with Web App, nice to know. It would resolve my issue if I had a number of different HTML-forms in my library. As I have only 1, I solved it with deploying the form on the client side, not good solution, but no need in extra step for user.

Comment: @Max Makhrov Thank you for replying and adding information.