# Apps Script Libary getting permissions issue with V8 runtime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a library who needs to process some data. And child script who use this lib.

Child script:

```
   function onOpen() {
  CustomLibrary.onOpen();
}

function run(){
  CustomLibrary.run();
}

function submit(){
  CustomLibrary.submit();
}

function refreshCountriesCurrencies(){
  CustomLibrary.refreshCountriesCurrencies();
}
```

When you start the function run()
the library opens an HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME with a part of HTML generated below (From CustomLib)

```
function createHtmlOutput_(report){
  console.log("Dans createHtmlOutput " + JSON.stringify(report))
  var htmlOutput = "";
  htmlOutput += "<script>";
  htmlOutput += "function submit(){";
  htmlOutput += "var content = document.getElementById(\"content\");";
  htmlOutput += "content.innerHTML = '<div style=\"text-align:center;\"><img id=\"loader\" style=\"margin-top:60px;\" height=\"60\" src=\"https://1ee06efa-a-2a899562\"/><p>Submitting values...</p></div>';";
  htmlOutput += "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).submit();";
```

the html generated by the lib, allows to click on a submit() button which will launch a function also called submit in the lib (function below belong de lib)

```
function submit(){
  console.log("CBCR Library submit()");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssid = ss.getId(); 
  adminRequest("submit",ssid);
}
```

But with runTime v8 the function is never called and returns a: You do not have access to perform that action. Please ask the owner of this item to grant access to you.
the error occurs at the time of the call to google.Script.run

If a disabled V8: it will work

and once, unchecking the V8 runtime was not enough, I had to delete the line "runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5" for it to work

Have you ever had this kind of problem? Do you know how to work around it without disabling the V8 runtime?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, for example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66711782/7108653

Comment: hello thx for your reply, unfortunately as my script work without V8 engine, doesn't seem to be this situation you mentioned

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Hello there @RaphaelObadia! I don't get any errors with the example code, could you please clarify the steps for reproduction? Also please share the minimal code that replicated the issue so we all can focus on it better.